# want to know concept behing Multilevel paging

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management, paging

In order to use large size page table hierarchical paging is done .
In case of two level page table scheme . for :
logical address space - 32bit - $2^32$ 
page size - 4kb i.e $2^12$

It is mentioned that page number is divided evenly :

```
i.e page number p1 - 10 bits
    page number p2 - 10 bits
    page offset d - 12bits.
```

I got this...... but my question is different. I didn't get the concept behind it.
What I thought for that I will take 1 example.

Take the address `0x00FF1234`. The binary representation of this address is `00000000111111110001001000110100`. By splitting this up, we get `0000000011 1111110001 001000110100`, or `0x3 0x3F1 0x234`.

`0000000011` this number  is pointing to 4th entry in the 1st level table. Means there are
 `0000000000` to `1111111111` unique numbers ( entries ) in the 1st level table. These gives the address of the 2nd level table.
 In this we are referring `0000000011` entry. Now does this entry contain some address which points to the base of the 2nd level table ? Now we are being pointed to 1111110001 address means `0000000011` containing `1111110001`  address ( I am thinking ) if yes then why only that address ? why not other address ?
Means here I want to ask what exactly happens behind this jumping. And how ? I read somewhere here about `CR3` register and all that but didn't get anything. I don't want that much deep. I just want to solve basic example of paging , TLB , virtual memory for GATE exam.
And what is this page size ( I always consider it as d as offset and solving problem )
For example : Page size is 1024 byte ... means d = 10 bytes. Does it mean , it ranges between 000....( 10 times) to 111....( 10 times) ? Not getting this concept properly.

Comment: Does the picture associated with this answer help?  http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11994/how-to-calculate-the-size-of-page-table.  Also take a look at http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/how-to-work-out-physical-address-corresponding-to-logical-address.