# How many page-table entries are needed in case the program uses the whole logical address space

Tags: operating-systems, paging

Say I have:

- page size = 2^12 bytes
- physical memory = 2^24 bytes
- logical address space = 2^32

How many page-table entries are needed in case the program uses the whole logical address space?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked at any of the dozens of quetions/answers on this site having to do with paging and page tables?  Try this one, for example: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/how-to-work-out-physical-address-corresponding-to-logical-address. This is a simple textbook division exercise.

Comment: @WanderingLogic I am just trying to understand whether my solution is correct. What I do is 2^32/3^12 = 2 ^22 and so that's the maximum number of entries. Although, I did make the question because my solution seemed trivial.

Comment: 2^32/2^12 is not 2^22, but otherwise you are doing it right